# Has anyone come across a rich GA framework in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am looking for something possibly as rich as JGAP framework (for Java), but for Ruby environment. The ones I have seen so far are fairly simplistic, and are not designed to be customised (I do not consider modifying of the existing framework class as a good way to extend).
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: @Mark That sounds like a good answer, actually.

Comment: Installing JRuby is additional complexity, which I would like to avoid. And also, extending the framework would be a bit awkward, e.g., adding new artefact, implementing new membership functions would have to be done either in Java (again, I want to avoid it), or in Ruby (I can't see this just yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure by GA you mean Google Analytics. If it is Google Analytics, [rugalytics](https://github.com/sbeckeriv/rugalytics) might help you

Of if it is Generic Algorithms then [gga4r](http://gga4r.rubyforge.org/) might be of any help.

Comment: GA is Genetic Algorithms. I have had a look at gga4r, so I guess this will be the answer eventually :) Thanks.

Comment: Hmm good to know. by the way why do you select ruby for genetic algo programming. what is the selection criteria.

Comment: The main reason for ruby is that my semantic model is written in it (for various reasons, which were not entirely up to me). It is not a problem, speed is not the issue here, and ruby has got quite a lot of nice features, so it is reasonable for my current needs.